# PHP time section of date as text

Tags: php, datetime, text, time

**Is it possible to print time information as text rather than digits?**

I know PHP makes provision for dates to be printed as text like in the following example:

```
// Prints something like: Monday 8th of August 2005 03:12:46 PM
echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
```

However, I'm looking for a solution to get the time section, i:e **date('h:i:s A')**, as text.

Comment: It is possible. Just write a function that converts the time into words. But there is nothing native in PHP to do it.

Comment: What do you want it to print, "12 minutes, 46 seconds after 3 o'clock in the afternoon"?

Comment: I'm missing something here as well.  h:i:s A will return "03:12:46 PM"  What do you want it to do?

Comment: @Barmar: that's exactly what I'm attempting to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Nothing built into PHP to allow this - but it can be done programatically.

One example (sadly not on SO) : http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?69321-A-clock-but-displayed-as-words/page3 should give you some pointers though.

Answer (score 0):

**this will do**

```
$val =  date('A');
echo date('i \m\i\n\u\t\e\s s \s\e\c\o\n\d\s \a\f\t\e\r h \o\'\c\l\o\c\k ');
echo (($val=="PM")?"in the afternoon":"in the morning");
//01 minutes 56 seconds after 07 o'clock in the afternoon
```

Comment: Why did you escape each char, vs `echo date('i')."minutes ".date('s')." seconds after ".date('h')." o'clock";`?

Comment: @RyanB B-  but is it good to use three functions in place of one?? i am confused whether its effective.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but my way will add some load time, maybe half a millisecond or less. However, think about ease of editing vs load.